# How do i continue this while

Tags: c++, while-loop

Im stuck with this program. What program does is to take a integer from user and display all number that are left after cutting the even numbers.

```
int main(){
    long n, minder=0;
    int cdonr, power=1;


    cout<<"Give a positive number "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    while (n>0){
        cdonr=n%10;
        if(cdonr % 2 != 0){
            minder=minder+cdonr*power;
            power=power*10;
        }
        n=n/10;

    }
    cout<<"The number that is left after all even number " << endl;
    cout<<minder<<endl;
    cout<<"Give a positive nr "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
}
```

Can someone help me with this while because after it split the first numbers it gives no response at the second one.

Thanks to people on this community this is the answer

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long n, minder = 0;
    int cdonr, power = 1;

    cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    while (n > 0) {
        while (n > 0) {
            cdonr = n % 10;
            if (cdonr % 2 != 0) {
                minder = minder + cdonr * power;
                power = power * 10;
            }
            //always zero so we need a nested while loop
            n = n / 10;
        }

        cout << "The number that is left after all even number " << endl;
        cout << minder << endl;

        //have to set values to default so they do not hold previous values
        minder = 0;
        cdonr = 0;
        power = 1;

        //we can reprompt user for a value
        //n will get set and it validates with the outer while loop
        //this allows it to run as many times as valid inputs
        cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does it crash with?

Comment: It functions at the first one but at the second doesn't give any answer

Comment: input: 123    output:13    input:1234    output:nothing

Comment: @UlikMadik Why do you expect for it to output anything, for your second input, if reading such input, is the last thing your program does?

Comment: You don't do anything after the last `cin`.

Comment: Well you don't have any code after the second input, that's why it ends

Comment: Add a function that includes the `while` and pass in n, which will easily solve your problem of doing nothing with the last `cin` and clean up your code as you don't need to have two `while` loops

Comment: I'd read into a `std::string` and look at the individual characters. Much simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer as requested by user, exits upon `== 0, <= 0, and not a number`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long n, minder = 0;
    int cdonr, power = 1;

    cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    while (n > 0) {
        while (n > 0) {
            cdonr = n % 10;
            if (cdonr % 2 != 0) {
                minder = minder + cdonr * power;
                power = power * 10;
            }
            //always zero so we need a nested while loop
            n = n / 10;
        }

        cout << "The number that is left after all even number " << endl;
        cout << minder << endl;

        //have to set values to default so they do not hold previous values
        minder = 0;
        cdonr = 0;
        power = 1;

        //we can reprompt user for a value
        //n will get set and it validates with the outer while loop
        //this allows it to run as many times as valid inputs
        cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is not infinite and you can do it as many times as you want by calling the function.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void function(long n, long minder, int cdonr, int power) {

    while (n > 0) {
        cdonr = n % 10;
        if (cdonr % 2 != 0) {
            minder = minder + cdonr * power;
            power = power * 10;
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }

    cout << "The number that is left after all even number " << endl;
    cout << minder << endl;
}

int main() {

    long n, minder = 0;
    int cdonr, power = 1;

    //can add a while loop here or just use a for
    // if you know how many times you want

    cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    if(n > 0){
    function(n, minder, cdonr, power);
    }

    //probably add an else here in case of == 0 or < 0
    // or just loop back if while

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the program but is there a more easy way? I would really like to put all the things in int main

Comment: Yes, after I posted this I thought about it some more. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do something forever, loop on it.
i.e. put your "function" to be repeated in a loop.
(And consider pulling it out to be an actual function)

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    while (true)
    {
        long n, minder = 0;
        int cdonr, power = 1;
        cout << "Give a positive number " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        while (n > 0) {
            cdonr = n % 10;
            if (cdonr % 2 != 0) {
                minder = minder + cdonr*power;
                power = power * 10;
            }
            n = n / 10;

        }
        cout << "The number that is left after all even number " << endl;
        cout << minder << endl;
    }
}
```